# Filtering child table in Db Adapter on Oracle Service Bus

Tags: oracle, orm, jdeveloper, osb

I have a self-related table containing both active and historical data (field **status** holding 'A'(ctive) or 'H'(istorical) )

I need to create a service returning active records with all their active children.

I may add a condition to the main query but can not affect the "many" part of one-to-many relation: historical records are also retrieved. Is it possible to implement it without creating a pipeline looping through the service based on table with no relation? In pure eclipselink this may be achieved by utilizing DescriptorCustomizer, but I don't know whether this is valid solution for OSB.
Also I can not create a database view containing only active records.
BTW I'm on 12.2.1.1

Example table structure and data (for Oracle):

```
create table SELF_REL_TAB
(
  ID        number not null,
  PARENT_ID number,
  STATUS    varchar2(1)
);

comment on column SELF_REL_TAB.ID
  is 'Primary key';
comment on column SELF_REL_TAB.PARENT_ID
  is 'Self reference';
comment on column SELF_REL_TAB.STATUS
  is 'Status A(ctive)  H(istorical)';

alter table SELF_REL_TAB
  add constraint SRT_PK primary key (ID);
alter table SELF_REL_TAB
  add constraint SRT_SRT_FK foreign key (PARENT_ID)
  references SELF_REL_TAB (ID);

alter table SELF_REL_TAB
  add constraint srt_status_chk
  check (STATUS IN ('A','H'));

INSERT INTO SELF_REL_TAB VALUES (1, NULL, 'A');
INSERT INTO SELF_REL_TAB VALUES (2, 1, 'A');
INSERT INTO SELF_REL_TAB VALUES (3, 1, 'H');
```

Comment: Yes, but it would be easier to really answer your question if you posted the table definitions.

Comment: Thank you, @RogerCornejo, I've added table definition

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you solved it, but you can use **connect by** clause to do that.

```
select
  lpad(' ', 2*level) || id
from
  self_rel_tab
  where status = 'A'
start with
  parent_id is null
connect by
  prior id=parent_id
```

JP